# Sequelize: Updating Model and its Associations

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have the following tables:

1. `Event`
2. `Tasks`

and the following association

```
Event.hasMany(models.Tasks, {
      as: 'tasks',
       foreignKey: 'event_id'
})
```

I am using the following code to update an `Event` and an array of `Tasks`

```
db.Event.findOne({
    where: {
        id: eventToUpdate.id
    },
    include: [{
        model: db.Tasks,
        as: 'tasks',
    }]
}).then((existingEvent) => {
   // Loop through existingEvent attributes and existingEvent.dataValues.tasks and 
   // updated the attributes
}
```

However, when I update it:

```
        db.Event.update(existingEvent, { where: { id: existingEvent.id } })
            .then((updatedEvent) => {
                console.log(updatedEvent)
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log("Error + error)
            })
```

Only `Event` is updated in the database, but not its `Tasks`.

What am I doing wrong? or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: How about using the existingEvent object to update task params. `existingEvent.tasks.updateAttributes(taskParams).then(res => res).catch(es => ex);` . When you use `db.Event.update` it does not include `Tasks` by default

Comment: only `existingEvent.updateAttributes()` is available.  `existingEvent.tasks.updateAttributes()` is not.

Comment: are you including `tasks` in the `findOne` query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Difficult to update it in the comment. But this is what I would suggest to do,

```
db.Event.findOne({
    where: {
        id: eventToUpdate.id
    },
    include: [{
        model: db.Tasks,
        as: 'tasks',
    }]
}).then((existingEvent) => {
   return Promise.all(existingEvent.tasks.map(task => task.updateAttributes(taskParams).then(console.log).catch(console.log));
}
```

Comment: Thank you!.  Tasks is an array.  And updateAttributes is not available.

Comment: Updated the answer now